# Comparing string format in a file

Tags: c, file, makefile, adjacency-list

I'm currently working on a makefile program that uses a text file of one or more commands in the form

> "@target str1 : str2 str3 ......strn
>
> @cmd _______________"

and forms a data dependency graph from the targets and the commands given.

I understand how to construct an adjacency list. My main issue is analyzing the file to determine if it's in the correct format. I can't use `getline()` because the `@target` and `@cmd` boundaries are only ended when the file ends or when one of them is called again, not by whitespace. Is the only way to check it with an ugly amount of `if` statements and `fscanf()`?

Comment: Can you have `@target` and `@cmd` on the same line? Or does the `@` have to appear as the first character on a line? If it's the latter, then you'll still want to use `getline`.

Comment: Yes you can. The end of eligible "targets" does end with a new line or a space. Only by an error or by `@cmd`.

Comment: Are all the tokens separated by whitespace? Or for example, could you have `@target str1:str2` with no spaces around the colon?

Comment: It's specifically calls for whitespace around each string and the colon.

Comment: Then `char buffer[200]` and `while(fscanf(fp,"%199s",buffer)==1)` would be the best choice for reading the tokens. There are techniques to help reduce the number of `if` statements, but you would need to post a sample of your code with the `if` statements to get any specific advice on that.